# PDO lastInsertId(); ? return value from specific column of just inserted value

Tags: php, pdo

I need to return the value from my auto incremented column of the update that's just happened.

Basically I am updating a user with XYZ values:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

I need to get the new records value from ID column in the database which is auto incremented.

PDO `lastInsertId();` just returns the latest record and could be potentially dangerous on a high traffic site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you are using MySql??

From mysql site:

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

Further:

> If you insert multiple rows using a single INSERT statement, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value generated for the first inserted row only.

So it's save to use because it works on connection basis. And if you insert multiple rows you can combine it with PDO's `rowCount` method to get all inserted id's.

Comment: Perfect thank you, and yes using mySQL, so the LAST_INSERT_ID() is safe to use perfect.